# ComboBox filtering (cascading)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm developing an university schedule and I'm having a problem with `ComboBox` cascading, and I'm not finding the answer yet.
So what I want to do is to Filter the COURSE  based on CATHEDRA and YEAR.
So CATHEDRA is comboBox1, YEAR is comboBox2 and COURSE is comboBox3.
the Cathedra's data is used from the database, but the YEAR numers are used from the comboBox2 EDIT ITEMS (I put them myself LIKE : 1,2,3,4).
This is the Query I'm using for that gets me to an error :

```
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT idlcourse, name_of_course FROM tblCOURSE WHERE cathedra =@cathedra AND year=@year");     
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cathedra", comboBox1.Text);
cmd.Parametes.AddWithValue("@year", comboBox2.Text);
```

I am trying different type of codes but noone works so it would be very good if you can send me the whole code

PS: YEARS attribute type is `Numeric(18)`.
If someone could sove it for me I would be very thankful.

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: i get random errors. i think i've made a wrong syntax.
It would be good if u can tell me how to filter the comboBox3 by the selected values from comboBox1 and comboBox2

Comment: you really have to be more descriptive than just "random errors". Please put those errors in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's still some missing info from your question but here's what I see.

- YEAR is a numeric type so you should pass the value in as a decimal
- Indeed, you do have a syntax problem, on the last line you spelled `Parametes` instead of `Parameters` (maybe this was just a case of misspell in the question only)
- You don't validate the values you're putting into your query. If for some reason the ComboBox2.Text is not a string representation of a number, your query will error out. If the combobox text values are `String.Empty` (default for initial load if you don't set index), your query will run but not return the right results.

So, here is what you can do:

```
decimal yearValue = 0;          //local var to store year

//Check that user has selected something
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox1.Text) 
   && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBox2.Text) 
   && Decimal.TryParse(comboBox2.Text, out yearValue))
{
    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT idlcourse, name_of_course FROM tblCOURSE WHERE cathedra=@cathedra AND year=@year");      
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cathedra", comboBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", yearValue);      //Replaced with yearValue
}
else
{
    //Handle else case (e.g Display msg to user)
}
```

Basically, I do some checking of the the combobox values in the `if` statement. 
I have also used `Decimal.TryParse()` which will only return true if it can convert the string into a decimal. Seems like you have put numeric/integer values in the combobox anyways, but it doesn't hurt to do some additional enforcement. Now if it passes all these checks, it will run the query. If it doesn't pass, it's up to you how to handle it.

As for how to put these results in comboBox3, put the results of the query in a `List` object and bind it to its `DataSource`.